# Python: Executing funciton in future time period with continuious postponement?

Tags: python

I have a Django web app which is used by embedded systems to upload regular data, currently every 2 minutes, to the server where Django just pops it into a database.

I'd like to create an alert system where by if there's no data uploaded from the remote system in a time period, say 10 minutes for example, I raise an alarm on the server, via email or something.

In other programming languages/environments I'd create a 10 minute timer to execute a function in 10 minutes, but every time data is uploaded I'd restart the timer. Thus hopefully the timer would never expire and the expiry function would never get called.

I might well have missed something obvious but if there is something I have missed it. This just does not seem possible in Python. Have I missed something?

At present looks like I need an external daemon monitoring the database :-(

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `time` module for this:

```
import time

def didEventHappen():
    # insert appropriate logic here to check 
    # for what you want to check for every 10 minutes
    value = True # this is just a placeholder so the code runs
    return value

def notifyServer():
    print("Hello server, the event happened")

start = time.clock()
delay = 10 * 60 # 10 minutes, converted to seconds
while True:
    interval = time.clock() - start
    eventHappened = False
    if interval >= delay:
        eventHappened = didEventHappen()
        start = time.clock() # reset the timer
    if eventHappened:
        notifyServer()
    else:
        print("event did not happen")
```

Alternatively, you could use the [sched](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html) module.